# Transform data to start-stop / long format

Tags: r, dplyr, transform, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I want to do survival analysis with a cox regression. Therefore, I need to transform my data according to observation times to a start-stop format instead of just one time observation.

Example dataset:

- userid indicates user identifier
- day indicates days since first event
- status indicates if the event of interest happened this day (1 = yes, 0 = no)

```
da1 <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), day= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), status = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

da1
  userid day status
1      1   1      0
2      1   2      0
3      1   3      1
4      2   1      1
5      2   2      0
6      2   3      0
7      3   1      0
8      3   2      1
9      3   3      1
```

I want to have my data this format:

```
da2 <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), startday= c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2), endday = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), status = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1))

da2
  userid startday endday status
1      1        0      1      0
2      1        1      2      0
3      1        2      3      1
4      2        0      1      1
5      2        1      2      0
6      2        2      3      0
7      3        0      1      0
8      3        1      2      1
9      3        2      3      1
```

It would be great, if I would also have some code to aggregate the observations if more than one day occurs without an event in a row.

```
da3 <- data.frame(userid = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3), startday= c(0,2,0,2,0,1,2), endday = c(2,3,1,3,1,2,3), status = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1))

da3
  userid startday endday status
1      1        0      2      0
2      1        2      3      1
3      2        0      1      1
4      2        2      3      0
5      3        0      1      0
6      3        1      2      1
7      3        2      3      1
```

I have tried the following code, but it gives wrong results:

```
for (i in 1:max(da$userid)){
  obst<-sort(unique(da$day))
  stpT<-obst[1:which(obst==da$day[i])]
  id<-rep(i,length(stpT))
  stat<-c(rep(0,length(stpT)-1),da$status[i])                            
  strT<-lag(stpT,1);strT[1]=0 
  iln<-stpT-strT

  df<-data.frame(userid=id,Start=strT,Stop=stpT,Status=stat,ILen=iln)
  if(i==1){data_obs=df}
  else{data_obs=rbind(data_obs,df)}
}

data_obs<-merge(data_obs,data[,c('userid','X')],by='userid')
dim(data_obs)
```

Comment: Cox regression doesn't handle data such as you have. You need statistical help instead so you can formulate a proper analysis plan.

Answer (score 3):

We can `group_by` `userid` and create a sequence for `startday` from 0 to `max` value of `day` in group and `endday` from 1 to `max(day)`.

```
library(dplyr)

da1 %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%
  mutate(startday = seq(0, max(day) - 1), 
         endday = seq(max(day))) %>%
  select(-day)

#  userid status startday endday
#   <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>  <int>
#1      1      0        0      1
#2      1      0        1      2
#3      1      1        2      3
#4      2      1        0      1
#5      2      0        1      2
#6      2      0        2      3
#7      3      0        0      1
#8      3      1        1      2
#9      3      1        2      3
```

Comment: Thank you! This only works if the number of observations is equal for all users, right? Do you also know how to aggregate observations, if more than one days without the event occur right behind each other?

Comment: @Scijens No..this will also work if number of observations are unequal in each group.

Comment: You're right, I just had a problem with missing values. Thank you.